# How to make torrent like table of downloadable files with progress indicator cells OSX? Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am building an app for downloading files from server, I have a `NSTableViewController` with custom cell with progess indicator in it, but i have a problem with drawing cells for each row/downloadable file. When i start downloading it seems the progress cell is just a copy of a first created cell and progress updating is a bit fuzzy and when i select multiple rows to download it displays only one progress on the last selected row. If anyone can help telling me where I did wrong?

Here is the code for drawing the cells in `-(NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row` method:

```
    if([identifier isEqualToString:@"status"]) {
        if ([selectedIndexes count] >0) {
            for (indexNumber in selectedIndexes) {
                ProgressBarCell *statusCell = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"StatusCell" owner:self];
                progressCellArray = [self populateArrayOfProgressBarCells:selectedIndexes with:statusCell];
                if ([indexNumber integerValue] == row) {
                    if (downloadTask != nil) {

                        [statusCell.imageView
                            setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"downloading"]];
                        [statusCell.textField setStringValue:@"downloading"];
                        for (int i = 0; i < statusCell.progressBar.maxValue; i++) {
                            [statusCell.progressBar setDoubleValue:[self getProgressPercentageForRowIndex:[indexNumber integerValue]]];
                            [statusCell.progressBar displayIfNeeded];
                            [statusCell.progressBar setUsesThreadedAnimation:YES];
                            [statusCell.progressBar
                                startAnimation:statusCell.progressBar];
                        }
                        if (statusCell.progressBar.doubleValue == statusCell.progressBar.maxValue) {
                            [statusCell.textField setStringValue:@"downloaded"];
                            [statusCell.imageView setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"finishedDownload"]];
                        }
                        return statusCell;
                    }
                    return notSelectedStatusCell = statusCell;
                }
            }
        }
        return notSelectedStatusCell;

    }
```

Comment: `tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:` doesn't draw. `NSTableView` asks the delegate for a cell view by calling `tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:`. The cell view is added as subview of the table view. Invisible cell views are reused. To update the progress indicator (outside `tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:`) you can get the cell view with `viewAtColumn:row:makeIfNecessary:`.

Comment: thank you for your answer but it does'n solve my issue i'll try to make a short screen recording of the issue

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DlricKgf3_g
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oQaox65SYQQ

here are the videos with the issue

Answer (score 0):

`tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:` doesn't draw. `NSTableView` asks the delegate for a cell view by calling `tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:`. The cell view is added as subview of the table view. Invisible cell views are reused. You can't return the same cell view for multiple rows. `tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:` should return a cell view for the row and do nothing else. The values of the subviews of the cell view are set. Example:

```
- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
    DownloadItem *item = self.data[row];
    if ([tableColumn.identifier isEqualToString:@"status"]) {
        StatusCellView *statusCell = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:tableColumn.identifier owner:self];
        statusCell.progressIndicator.doubleValue = item.progress;       
        if (item.finished) {
            statusCell.textField.stringValue = @"downloaded";
            statusCell.imageView.image = [NSImage imageNamed:NSImageNameMenuOnStateTemplate];
        }
        else
            if (item.downloading) {
                statusCell.textField.stringValue = @"downloading";
                statusCell.imageView.image = [NSImage imageNamed:NSImageNameMenuMixedStateTemplate];
            }
            else {
                statusCell.textField.stringValue = @"paused";
                statusCell.imageView.image = nil;
            }
        return statusCell;
    }
    else {
        NSTableCellView *cellView = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:tableColumn.identifier owner:self];
        cellView.textField.stringValue = item.title;
        return cellView;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Reload the cell when the values change and the cell view should be updated. Example:

```
NSInteger row = [self.data indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:item];
NSInteger column = [self.tableView columnWithIdentifier:@"status"];
[self.tableView reloadDataForRowIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:row] columnIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:column]];
```